# When the query returns "0 RECORDS" or "NULL" return string

Tags: database, postgresql

When the query returns "0 RECORDS" or "NULL", I would like it to return "No Value" as the value

**TABLE**

```
create table registry
(
  column_value VARCHAR(30)
  );
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
COALESCE(NULLIF(column_value,'NO VALUE'),'NO VALUE')
FROM registry
```

**Expected outcome**

```
 |   column_value  |
 ___________________

 |    "No Value"   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are interested in a single row result of the query, you may use

```
SELECT
    coalesce( nullif( MAX(column_value),'0 RECORDS') ,'NO VALUE')
FROM registry
```

Aggregate function like `MAX` always return a row even if there aren't any rows returned from the query result.

I have used various examples in the demo below for a single row in the table. Have a look.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=49f0398b79b9a41a77cbb4df8e36c12c)